# What settings do I use in the default-ssl.conf file on an ubuntu server running an Omeka installation?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an installation of Omeka running on an Ubuntu server with Apache. I’ve loaded an SSL certificate and it seems fine, but only the first page of the site will load now. Anything else gives a ‘URL not found’ error. It doesn’t seem to matter what I set the `DocumentRoot` as. Right now it’s the default `/var/www/html` but I've tried multiple variations.

I'm assuming the issue is with DocumentRoot; that's the only thing that makes sense to me, but it could be something with Omeka itself that I'm missing.

I've modified the server-generated 000-default.conf file with `RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]  <Directory "/var/www/html" > AllowOverride All </Directory>`

Beyond that, all I did was load the certificates into `etc/ssl/certs` and `etc/ssl/private` and try `DocumentRoot` variations in the default-ssl.conf file

Comment: Hi Ezra, welcome to Serverfault. Please provide more data, for example Apache's config files that have been modified. Without more information, helping is very difficult.

Comment: @fuero I've modified the server-generated 000-default.conf file with `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
<Directory "/var/www/html" >
AllowOverride All
</Directory>`
Beyond that, all I did was load the certificates into `etc/ssl/certs` and `etc/ssl/private` and try variations in the default-ssl.conf file

Comment: Please modify your question to contain the data - the comments get quite messy.

Comment: Which URL is working, which aren't? What's in Apache's/PHP's logs when you access the URLs? What does your DocumentRoot look like?